# Word to describe a 'luxurious' person?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Entering the gates, I was greeted by the sight of _______ highschoolers.

Not *upper-class*, the person doesn't necessarily have to be a rich person. Not necessarily a *poseur*.

Comment: There are many possible answers. You'll have to narrow it down.

Comment: What do you mean by luxurious?  Paint us a picture.

Comment: All I can think of is ___posh___ https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/posh.

Answer (score 1):

"Preppy" (also "preppie") is quite relevant when talking about school students. A preppy doesn't necessarily have to be wealthy, but they give the impression they are based on their appearance, manner, dress etc.